# Gaussian measure of intersection of halfspaces

Tags: integration, probability-theory, gaussian-integral

Let $a_{1}, a_{2}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ be a Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and let $p$ denote its density. Consider the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\{x:~ a_{1}^{\top}x>0,~ a_{2}^{\top}x>0\}}p(x)dx,
\end{equation}
which is the measure (under $p$) of the intersection of the halfspaces determined by $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$. Is this integral known in closed form?

Comment: If $X$ is your $d$-dimensional random vector, the pair $(U,V)=(a_1^TX, a_2^TX)$ has a joint $2$-dimensional Gaussian distribution, from which it is easy to work out your integral.

Comment: @kimchilover Sure. I am actually trying to compute the joint pmf of the vector $(U',~V')$, wher $U'=\text{sign}(U)$ and $V'=\text{sign}(V)$. To compute $P(U'=1, ~V'=1)$, I need to evaluate the integral above

Comment: As @kimchilover pointed out, the joint density $p_{UV}$ of $(U,V)$ can be found, and this integral is basically integration of $p_{UV}$ over the positive orthant and this is discussed here <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals>. But for higher dimensions, there doesn't seem to be a closed form expression