# Fourth order statistc of sign function of random vector

Tags: probability, matrices, expected-value

we have this preposition as follows

$\textbf{Proposition}$: $\textit{let} \ \boldsymbol{\zeta} \sim
\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},{\gamma}\mathbf{I}_N). For \ \mathbf{a}_1 , \mathbf{a}_2 \in \ \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$

$\mathbb{E} [sgn({\mathbf{a}_1}^T \boldsymbol\zeta) sgn({\mathbf{a}_2}^T \boldsymbol\zeta)] = \Omega \bigg(\frac{{\mathbf{a}_1}^T \mathbf{a}_2}{||\mathbf{a}_1||||\mathbf{a}_2||} \bigg)$

where sgn is the sign function. $\Omega(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}$ arcsine($x$).

My question is how we can find following expression in closed-form

$\mathbb{E} [sgn({\mathbf{a}_1}^T \boldsymbol\zeta) sgn({\mathbf{a}_2}^T \boldsymbol\zeta)\ \mathbf{A}\ sgn({\mathbf{b}_1}^T \boldsymbol\eta) sgn({\mathbf{b}_2}^T \boldsymbol\eta)] $

where matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is given, and the definition of $\mathbf{b}$ and random vector $\boldsymbol\eta$ is the same with $\mathbf{a}$ and $\boldsymbol\zeta$ respectively, just with different size (lets say $\in \ \mathbb{R}^{M \times 1}$). Indeed, I'm looking for another preposition for this case.

thanks

Comment: Maybe connected to [Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis'_theorem) ?

Comment: I don't think so. I think that is for normal distribution. here after sign function we don't know the distribution.

Comment: Actually, there is no closed-form expression for joint probability of 4 multivariate normal variables bigger than 0 . But still I'm thinking maybe there is some trick to find the expected value.

Comment: To find that we need to compute
$\mathbb{E} [sgn(X_1) sgn(X_2) sgn(X_3) sgn(X_4)] = \mathbb P(X_1>0, X_2>0, X_3>0, X_4>0) - \mathbb P(X_1<0, X_2>0, X_3>0, X_4>0) + \ldots$

here we have the closed form for $\mathbb P(X_1>0, X_2>0, X_3>0, X_4>0)$ based on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals/3148280#3148280. but unfortunately not for other terms.