# Gaussian integrals over an intersection of two half-spaces

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

Let $W_1, W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $x, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, I am trying to integrate a Gaussian over the intersection of two half-space:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \int_{\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2} \exp\left(-\frac{\left\Vert x - t \right\Vert_2^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) d t
$$
where
$$
\Omega_1 = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: W_1 z + b_1 \geq 0 \right\} 
$$
and
$$
\Omega_2 = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: W_2 z + b_2 \geq 0 \right\}
$$

Related questions have been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556977/gaussian-integrals-over-a-half-space) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241176/probablity-of-gaussian-vector-falling-into-the-instersection-of-two-half-spaces) but I still haven't figure out a proper way to compute this integral.
I also wondering if the result from this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/118761) can be of help.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think that you have any hope of an analytic expression in terms of elementary functions.  There *might* be something "nice" in terms of the $\operatorname{erf}$ function, but the best that I would expect would be a numerical result.

Comment: An expression with the erf function would be great, if that's possible

Comment: One point to simplify matters is to start with lower-dimensional examples. The case of $n=1$ is probably too simple to be interesting, but $n=2$ already looks quite difficult with the range of possible parameters.

Comment: Not sure that "half-spaces"  in your title is literally correct. Have you sketched examples in 2D and perhaps 3D?

Comment: I am not sure why that would be incorrect. In 1 dimension, the set ${z \in \mathbf{R} : w x + b \geq 0 }$ defines a half-space right? Do you mean that $W_1$ and $W_2$ would need to be vectors?

Comment: In 3D I  think $\Omega_1$ is like a coordinate octant that has been  distorted by a linear transformation so that its walls do not meet at right angles, and the intersection of two such regions is complicated. In 2D the intersection is a quadrilateral formed by two V-shaped wedges.

Comment: The vector b has the effect of shifting the vertex of the Vee-shaped region.